# Bing Maps v7 - Polygon blocks mouseover events for pins displayed within (behind) the polygons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bing-maps

I'm using the current version of Bing maps and I'm basically displaying a regional map where I have areas colour coded as polygone shapes and I'm displaying points of interest within those polygons. The issue is that the pins displayed within the polygons do not generate popups when moused over or any other events while those pins displayed outside of the polygons do.

Currently, all of the pins and the polygons exist wihin the same layer.

The polygone areas are defined with separate location array.
I've tried separating the layers, adding to a single layer in different sequence (i.e. add polygons first to layer and then pins) but still no joy.

Other details as well,

using Richard Brundritt's client side clustering for grouping pins

Data is sourced from sql 2008 Geography data type for filtering locations with JSON request to get data.

asp.net framework 4

Bing Maps v7 AJAX implementation

I'm still experimenting (will see if tileLayer will work) but any help in the direction I should be going would be greatful.

David

Answer (score 1):

First, are you sure that your Pushpins and the Polygons are within the same [EntityCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427616.aspx) on the map?  If they are not, then you need to make sure that the EntityCollection which contains the Polygons does not have a higher [zIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427614.aspx) than the EntityCollection which contains the Pushpins.  If they are all within the same EntityCollection, try setting the [zIndex of your Pushpins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427629.aspx) explicitly to some high numeric value, and see if that helps.

Comment: Hey Bojin, I originally did try setting the zindex value of the polygon entitycollection layer (tried setting to -1) with no luck but doing some more review, I found a method in clustering routines that sets all existing entitycollections zindexs to 0 then the pin layer to 1 (BringLayerToFront). using this method I was able to add my polygon entitycollection and then the pin entitycollection and have the pins take precidence ove all others. Voted up your answer since it was on the right track...Thanks for input.